# Asterisks in XML attribute value

Tags: xml, validation, xhtml

I have an XHTML file, with this line:

```
<tr id="some-string-with-a-*">
```

and I get the validation error:

> Syntax of value for attribute id of tr is not valid

I changed it to `&#42;` and I still get the same error.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an asterisk:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

See the Fragment Identifiers section of the [XHTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/):

> Note that the collection of legal values in XML 1.0 Section 2.3,
>   production 5 is much larger than that permitted to be used in the ID
>   and NAME types defined in HTML 4. When defining fragment identifiers
>   to be backward-compatible, only strings matching the pattern
>   [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9:_.-]* should be used. See Section 6.2 of [HTML4]
>   for more information.

Note that if you don't want to support backwards compatibility, there are additional characters allowed as per XML, but asterisk isn't in that list either:

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation. However I can use for example some entity, i.e. `&acirc;` and it won't raise validation error. That's why I thought that there is maybe some way for workaround.